# How to read incoming TCP data packets by packets in C# (i.e., without concatenation of packets)?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I'm actually sending data from Matlab to update a UNITY scene : - Matlab send "a" or "b" to UNITY, using TCP protocol - UNITY receive "a" or "b", and update the color of an object based on this character

I've got an issue with the update of my variable called "coherence" in UNITY. When the script is running, packets of data coming from MATLAB are concatenating. For exemple, if I print "coherence" in the log file, it looks like "aaaaababbbbbbbbaaaaabbbbbbababababbbbaaababbaabbbaba". What I would like, is my last packet of data to be the only one to be read and print (e.g, "coherence" is "a", then "b", then "b", then "a" and so on, instead of being "a" then "ab" then "abb" then "abba" ...).

Can you tell me if something is wrong in my code please ? Is the instruction "ReadToEnd" is ok ?

Thanks a lot for your input,

Yannick

```
// Use this for initialization of TCP Server 

TcpListener listener; 
String coherence;

// Initialization of the script 
void Start() 
{ 
     _renderer = GetComponent(); 
listener = new TcpListener(55001); 
listener.Start(); 
print("is listening"); 
}

void Update() 
{

                     if (!listener.Pending())
                     {
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         print("socket comes");
                         TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                         NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
                         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ns);
                         coherence = reader.ReadToEnd();
                         print(coherence);
                     }



             if (coherence == "a")
             {
                 colorFin = Color.green;
             }

             else if (coherence == "b")
             {
                 colorFin = Color.yellow;
             }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike UDP, TCP is logically a stream API, not a packet API. While at some low levels it *may be possible* to access the raw packets, virtually all *consumer* APIs expose it as a stream, with no guarantee that receives will match sends in terms of the original *packet* layout. Instead, what is guaranteed is: same bytes, same order. This means that you need to implement some kind of "framing" protocol. For a text-based protocol this often means simply: lines - i.e. add a CR/LF/CRLF after each complete message. For binary protocols, this usually means some kind of length prefix *before* each complete message.

Note that `ReadToEnd()` is only usable if you expect all the data to come at once (instead of via a x/y/x/y/x/y conversation between the two endpoints); although personally I'd recommed avoiding `StreamReader` *entirely* when using sockets, and just use the raw socket API or stream API. It is easy for code like `ReadToEnd` to block forever. If this is a *client* that only expects a single socket, that might be OK, but for a *server* (with lots of sockets), it is terrible: a malicious client can lock a thread *forever* by simply sending `"Hi"` and not disconnecting. This will never satisfy `ReadToEnd`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Marc. Based on your answer, the best will be to switch to UDP protocl isn't it ? I'm very new at C# programming, and since I did changes for UDP client on Matlab easily, I'm still having trouble with C# for UNITY as server. Can you please give me your advice on what code to change based on my first script version, provided earlier ? I thought it would be only a matter of changing "TcpListener" to "UdpListener", but it clearly needs more. I had a look at Google to find code, but I can't find generic script. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Yannick_Da without knowledge of what you're doing, it is impossible for me to comment on whether TCP or UDP is more appropriate. By default, I would say that your best bet is simply to *add framing* - i.e. add some kind of terminator to logical messages, such as a CRLF. If you don't control the other end, maybe figure out why framing doesn't matter to them - it might make perfect sense without frames. You can't just change one end here - if you change your half to UDP, you also need to change whatever is sending the data to use UDP.